# Set leaf nodes' size d3.treemap

Tags: d3.js, nodes, treemap

I have started using `d3` lately. I am interested if is there any possibility to set the size of leaf nodes using `d3.treemap()`?

I would like to have the leaf nodes of the same size, and after I want the `d3` to generate a treemap layout.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout):

> The value accessor is invoked for each input data element, and must return a number representing the numeric value of the node. This value is used to set the area of each node proportionally to the value.

You can't set the size explicitly (as this is computed by the layout), but whatever is returned as value for a leaf node affects the size of the rectangle relative to the other ones.